# How to copy files from github to container running on VSTS agent in Azure Devops CI pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm building a windows container and want to copy some files from github to my container which was built inside the VSTS agent (azure devops).

I created a copy task from list of inbuilt tasks in pipelines, but not sure how it will work.

YAML is:

```
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: ..
    Contents: |
     default.aspx
     web.config
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

I just need to copy default.aspx and web.config from github to container inside my VSTS agent.
The target path is c:\inetpub\wwwroot inside the container.

Or instead of this can i use some copy steps in my dockerfile ?

My docker file is simple:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis

SHELL ["powershell"]

RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET ; \
    Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45
    
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Do you have any issue when you use CopyFiles task?

Comment: Thanks Cece. Copy task doesn't seem to work , when i specify c:\inetpub\wwwroot as destnation, it copies files to the VSTS agent rather than the container. I've tried prefixing container id to the path, which fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have this folder structure:

```
root-folder:
  DOCKERFILE
  content:
    default.aspx
    web.config
```

Accodringly to [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/iis-docker) you should be good to go adding these lines:

```
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY content/ .
```

Putting all together:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis

SHELL ["powershell"]

RUN Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET ; \
    Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45
    
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY content/ .

EXPOSE 80
```

But my assumptions is folder structure above. If you have different you should copy your files use `CopyFiles@2` task.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, i had to create a separate "content" directory in github and move my content there. After this dockerfile was able to pick up the source path.

Comment: That also would work! I'm happy that we solved your issue!